# After a successful registration with email and password, can I add the email automatically to real-time database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

///
create account to fireBase now
///
how do I add  the registered email to my realtime database
/// 
Or is it possible to obtain the email address while registering? I am really stuck

```
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        //my action

                        sendEmailVerificationMessage();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    } else {
                       //my second action
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `if (task.isSuccessful()) {`, you can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
ref.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("email").setValue(email);
```

This will create the following in the database:

```
users
  userId
     email: userEmail
```

Answer (score 1):

After you press the register button, you will send the email and password to Firebase with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)...`, this method has a callback that will notify when the user has been created, then inside that callback you can get the current logged in user email and send it to the database

Since the task is an [AuthResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult), you can get the user and get the email to send

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        //my action

                        mDatabaseRef.child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("email").setValue(task.getUser().getEmail());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    } else {
                       //my second action
                    }
                });
```

`getUser()` is of type [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser), you can check there what you can request

Comment: Thanks a lot, the link contains a lot of functions I even didn't even know exist